# Accessing d3 data for tooltip display

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm still deep in the beginning stages of learning how to manipulate javascript and d3, and after searching around, I can't figure out how to get the right information into my tooltips.

I've taken an already-coded [hexbin script](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/hexbins/starbucks.html) and have replaced it with school data in .csv form. It displays correctly on the [map](http://test.indiscreetacumen.com/schoolV.html). However, when I try to pass in the school name information for the tooltip, I get:

> [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.school')
>     (anonymous function) (d3.min.js, line 1)

I try to call the school name with this code:

```
 function makePie (data) {
              var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip")
              .html(function(d){
                    return d.school;
                    })
            }
```

With my full script here:

```
  L.HexbinLayer = L.Class.extend({
    includes: L.Mixin.Events,
    initialize: function (rawData, options) {
      this.levels = {};
      this.layout = d3.hexbin().radius(10);
      this.rscale = d3.scale.sqrt().range([0, 10]).clamp(false);
      this.rwData = rawData;
      this.config = options;
    },
    project: function(x) {
      var point = this.map.latLngToLayerPoint([x[1], x[0]]);
      return [point.x, point.y];
    },
    getBounds: function(d) {
      var b = d3.geo.bounds(d)
      return L.bounds(this.project([b[0][0], b[1][1]]), this.project([b[1][0], b[0][1]]));
    },
    update: function () {
      var pad = 100, xy = this.getBounds(this.rwData), zoom = this.map.getZoom();

      this.container
        .attr("width", xy.getSize().x + (2 * pad))
        .attr("height", xy.getSize().y + (2 * pad))
        .style("margin-left", (xy.min.x - pad) + "px")
        .style("margin-top", (xy.min.y - pad) + "px");

      if (!(zoom in this.levels)) {
          this.levels[zoom] = this.container.append("g").attr("class", "zoom-" + zoom);
          this.genHexagons(this.levels[zoom]);
          this.levels[zoom].attr("transform", "translate(" + -(xy.min.x - pad) + "," + -(xy.min.y - pad) + ")");
      }
      if (this.curLevel) {
        this.curLevel.style("display", "none");
      }
      this.curLevel = this.levels[zoom];
      this.curLevel.style("display", "inline");
    },
    genHexagons: function (container) {
      var data = this.rwData.features.map(function (d) {
        var coords = this.project(d.geometry.coordinates)
        return [coords[0],coords[1], d.properties];
      }, this);

      var bins = this.layout(data);
      var hexagons = container.selectAll(".hexagon").data(bins);

      var counts = [];
      bins.map(function (elem) { counts.push(elem.length) });
      this.rscale.domain([0, (ss.mean(counts) + (ss.standard_deviation(counts) * 10))]);

      var path = hexagons.enter().append("path").attr("class", "hexagon");
      this.config.style.call(this, path);

      that = this;
      hexagons
        .attr("d", function(d) { return that.layout.hexagon(that.rscale(d.length)); })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .on("mouseover", function (d) { 
          var s=0, k=0;

          that.config.mouse.call(this, [s,k]);
          d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("visibility", "visible")
            .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 115)+"px"})
          .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 115)+"px";});
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });
    },
    addTo: function (map) {
      map.addLayer(this);
      return this;
    },
    onAdd: function (map) {
      this.map = map;
      var overlayPane = this.map.getPanes().overlayPane;

      if (!this.container || overlayPane.empty) {
          this.container = d3.select(overlayPane)
              .append('svg')
                  .attr("id", "hex-svg")
                  .attr('class', 'leaflet-layer leaflet-zoom-hide');
      }
      map.on({ 'moveend': this.update }, this);
      this.update();
    }
  });

  L.hexbinLayer = function (data, styleFunction) {
    return new L.HexbinLayer(data, styleFunction);
  };
  //**********************************************************************************
  //********  IMPORT DATA AND REFORMAT ***********************************************
  //**********************************************************************************
  d3.csv('http://test.indiscreetacumen.com/schoolRawV.csv', function (error, schools) {

    function reformat (array) {
      var data = [];
      array.map(function (d){
        data.push({
          properties: {
            nfree: +d.nfree,
            free: +d.free,
            school: d.school
          }, 
          type: "Feature", 
          geometry: {
            coordinates:[+d.longitude,+d.latitude], 
            type:"Point"
          }
        });
      });

      return data;

    }
    var geoData = { type: "FeatureCollection", features: reformat(schools) };


    //**********************************************************************************
    //********  CREATE LEAFLET MAP *****************************************************
    //**********************************************************************************
    var cscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range(["#00FF00","#FFA500"]);

    // PLEASE DO NOT USE MY MAP ID :)  YOU CAN GET YOUR OWN FOR FREE AT MAPBOX.COM
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZG5ld21zIiwiYSI6IlR6WE9kUDAifQ.IXJ0PfUXntjO2LeyaxDzWw';
    var leafletMap = L.mapbox.map('mapContainer', 'dnewms.4e733c6b')
        .setView([47.62, -122.362], 11);

    //**********************************************************************************
    //********  ADD HEXBIN LAYER TO MAP AND DEFINE HEXBIN STYLE FUNCTION ***************
    //**********************************************************************************
    var hexLayer = L.hexbinLayer(geoData, { 
                      style: hexbinStyle,
                      mouse: schoolName
                    }).addTo(leafletMap);

    function hexbinStyle(hexagons) {
      hexagons
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
                          var avg = d3.mean(d, function(d) { return +d[2].free; })
                          return cscale(avg);
          })
        };

    //**********************************************************************************
    //********  PIE CHART ROLL-OVER ****************************************************
    //**********************************************************************************
   function schoolName (hexagons) {
      var svg = d3.select("#tooltip").select("svg")
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

      var g = svg.selectAll("svg")
                .data(schools)
                    .enter().append("g");


          g.append("text")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text(function (d, i) {
                         return d.school;
                                }); 
}
  });
```

I know importing the data for the map puts it into nests, but I'm not sure how to drill down to the school name when the script seems to lose the reference to 'd'.

Thanks, and feel free to point me to answers I may not have uncovered yet.

Comment: Can you put this running code on a fiddle, it will be very helpful.

Comment: It looks like you're setting the mouse event to occur on the hexbin layer that you call from Leaflet.  You probably want to have the mouse event be attached to the elements that you create from your bound data.  In this case, that is `hexagons`.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the bottom portion of my code, and now can access the data. However, the tooltip display all the school names overlapping each other. Do I remap the data?